# Check if polygon is inside polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry, collision-detection

So, this is a well discussed subject, but it seems to always end up with algorithms doing the point-in-polygon operation extended with edge intersection detection for cases where the outer polygon is concave. What if inner (yellow) and outer polygons (red and blue)) has all of its vertices on the main polygon's edges or vertices?

Consider the following example:
[image: polygon inside polygon]

Polygon B is inside polygon A although polygon B does not have any vertices inside polygon A. All of polygon B's vertices are on polygon A's edges/vertices. Same goes with polygon C and D, but they are outside polygon A.

Point-in-polygon and edge intersections does not give different results for polygon B vs. polygon C and D, so how come these operations are the way to do it for so many people out there?

Comment: "*What if inner and outer polygons has all of its vertices on the main polygon's edges or vertices?*" Then, as a matter of programming, it all comes down to numerical precision. You can use <= rather than <, but numerical precision in floating-point math will make it very difficult to ensure that it always would work.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with numerical precision as we suppose all vertices are on boundary, which means we have solved the precision problem already.

Comment: This may not be entirely correct. The problem is that the definition of "on boundary" already **is** subject to these inaccuracies. One corner point of C could have an x-coordinate that, *mathematically*, should be 5.0, but, due to the inaccuracies, may actually have a value like 4.9999999999313 or 5.00000000005423, letting it clearly be considered as *inside* or *outside* of A (but **not** "on the boundary"). Something like this basically always boils down to messing around with seemingly arbitrary "epsilons". A bit far-fetched, but related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/73601

Comment: Due to floating point number precision, I think 4.9999999999313 and 5.00000000005423 are the same value (using a threshold) when it comes to detecting where the point is, meaning we cant say it's inside or outside (but rather close to boundary). My first thought on this problem, is that it's not about number precision at all, but rather whether all EDGES are inside the polygon or not, not only vertices.

Comment: A sweep-line algorithm wouldn't have any problem with this at all. It would effectively convert the 2d problem into a bunch of 1d problems that are much simpler to solve.

Comment: That's a good approach! When performance is an issue, it's good if one single sweep-line is enough. That actually boils down to point-in-polygon operation, where choosing the point becomes the central part of solving this problem. Considering our precondition saying that the polygon is entirely inside or outside the other polygon, the point to check could be somewhere on an edge which is not on the boundary of the other polygon.

Comment: Ah, well, I didn't notice that it's known there are no partial intersections. Then this is really easy. Project the polygons onto the x axis (i.e ignore y coordinates). There are either no intersections or you can check any vertex that's "inside" an overlap in the 1d projection. If the x-axis project is ambiguous - regions are identical for both - then repeat with the y-axis projection.